# unir dos archivos en pandas omitiendo la infornacion de la intersección

Tags: python, pandas

Buen día estoy intentando unir dos archivos en pandas con el método merge, pero necesito que solo me deje la unión de los archivos sin la intersección de los datos ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Adjunta tu código para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Para poder ayudarte necesitamos el código que estás ejecutando, el input y el resultado esperado. Así podremos ayudarte fácilmente :)

Comment: Seguramente necesites `merge` con indicator =True y despues seleccionar donde la columna `_merge` es distinto de `both`